# Installing my modules in React ts App is very slow

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-hooks

`npm  -v`   8.4.1
`node -v`   v16.13.2

typing `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`, take very long time to install all dependencies, in particular for

> - mymodule1
> - mymodule2
> - mymodule3

thats are my owwns moudules.

Here my package.json

```
  "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PUBLIC_URL=/ webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",

  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "myurl"
  },
  "author": "Andrea Lunetta",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.36",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/redux-actions": "2.6.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux-actions": "2.6.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-observable": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.64.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0",
    "myModule1": "git+ssh://myrepo.com/myModule1#testing",
    "myModule2": "git+ssh://myrepo.com/myModule2#testing",
    "myModule3":"git+ssh://myrepo.com/myModule3#testing",
  
  }
}
```

Installing these dependendecies except for mymodules is fast. But installing my modules take very long time around 15 minutes.
Is there a way to speed up this process by not using the `npm link`?